# Is this quote grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> Beauty and sadness always go together.
>   Nature thought beauty too rich to go
>   forth upon the earth without a meet
>   alloy. (George MacDonald)

The last part of the quote doesn't seem to make sense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Nature thought beauty too rich to go forth upon the earth without a meet alloy.

Several words here are omitted for style. Restoring them we get:

> Nature thought [that] beauty [was] too rich to go forth upon the earth without a meet alloy.

The key ideas here are:

**rich** is used metaphorically, to indicate that beauty is too wonderful and powerful to leave alone.

**to go forth upon the earth** is just a poetic way of saying "to go out" or "to go free".

**meet** here is an adjective (not a verb!) that means "fitting" or "suitable". This usage of the word "meet" is very archaic and poetic.

**alloy** is used metaphorically as well, to mean something like "companion".

So a colloquial translation would be something like "Nature thought beauty was too great to be let out alone without something to accompany it."

Comment: +1 for simplifying it to "Nature thought beauty was too great to be let out alone without something to accompany it." - well done.

Answer (score 5):

**[meet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meet%5B3%5D)** *adj.*

> precisely adapted to a particular situation, need, or circumstance : very proper

**[alloy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alloy)** *n.* (4th definition)

> a compound, mixture, or union of different things <an ethnic alloy of many peoples>

So a "meet alloy" would mean a "very proper union":

> Nature thought beauty too rich to go forth upon the earth without a **very proper mixture**

It's *grammatically* correct.  But the structure of the sentence seems to specify that the alloy is *possessed* by beauty, which would be incorrect, since an *alloy* refers to the combination itself — including "beauty".  **Companion** or a similar word seems to fit better.

Instead of this being incorrect though, I more think that the author meant to imply that the alloy was to be provided alongside, not possessed, by beauty.

Answer (score 2):

In this case 'meet' is not a verb it is an archaic adjective for expressing 'fitting'.

> [Meet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/meet): archaic proper, fitting, or correct

An alloy is a mixture of two metals, usually with one being of lesser value.

In others words, "beauty was too powerful to go into the world without another baser element to corrupt it." (beauty would just be too attractive without a downside.)

Answer (score -1):

In the movie *Jane Eyre* (and maybe the book, too), a character tells Jane, "I wonder if we do not share the same **alloy**." In context, *alloy* here means grief.

I wonder if this is the same usage, of a complement to something good or so.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Ros.  Unfortunately, you have proved more of a comment than an answer proper. Once you gai na few more reputation points on the site, you will be able to post comments in the actual comment area.

Comment: That looks like a good find. Have you anything to show that *alloy* means 'grief', other than 'by context'? In fact, I do not see how 'grief' could be implied in the context. If you provide more substantiating information, this could be a good answer. (Which it at present it is not.)

Comment: A Google search indicates the phrase only occurs in the film. It's always good to include the context too; and needed here because it's not in the book.

Comment: (forgive me for not knowing how to use the website properly yet...)
Sure, the context is: Jane Eyre goes to work to St John Rivers, he asks her if she feels solitude, she says she doesn't. He replies that she then might be "dwelling on things past", and then says:

St John: But I counsel you to resist firmly every temptation to look back.
Jane Eyre: That's what I intend to do.
St John: A year ago, I was myself intensely miserable. I scorned this weakness, fought hard against it and won. I wonder if we do not share the same alloy.

Comment: Furthermore, please go to http://www2.hn.psu.edu/faculty/jmanis/bronte/jane-eyre.pdf and search the word alloy. It appears in other phrases and it might help us understand the meaning properly.

Comment: More: alloy usage as a metaphor: http://mind.textdriven.com/db/browse.php?mode=1&filter=metaphor.SubCategory&fvalue=Alloy