# Did the author of the following text mean "meat?"

Tags: semantics

"Small initial discrepancies may not be seen as meet for a federal case, particularly when the employee, trying to succeed in a nontraditional environment, is averse to making waves."  Is there a legalistic meaning for *meet* or did the author mean to use the word *meat* in the text quoted above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this quote grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26711/is-this-quote-grammatically-correct)

Answer (score 3):

No, the term **[meet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meet?q=meet)** as an adjective, although often thought of as archaic, means

> suitable or proper

Comment: It's not quite archaic, at least not in the negative: see Ngrams for the phrase [is not meet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+not+meet%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+is+not+meet%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20meet%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20meet%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I’ve often noticed that people think any word they do not themselves use in casual chitchat is wont to get relegated to *archaic* in their eyes, not recognizing that there are different registers, especially written ones, or different styles than their own.

Comment: @tchrist Us leagal types have no prob with *meet* and such, but inasmuch as I don't trust our sensibilities, I hereto for thought that all we find sympatico is/are archaic.

Comment: @PeterShor Nor to those raise in a [Roman Catholic liturgy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sursum_corda) of the 50s